# How to fix Stripe Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Must provide source or customer...?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

Just wondering if anyone has any idea how to fix this error as I'm not sure. I'm aware there are similar questions but their full error is different.

Full Error HERE:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Must provide source or customer. in /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php:110 from API request 'req_N9vZa4brfYHaam' Stack trace: #0 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(275): Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Array, Array) #1 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(65): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Array) #2 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(120): Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/charges', Array, Array) #3 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(159): Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/charges', Array, NULL) #4 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/Charge.php(74): Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL) #5 /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/charge.php(17): Stripe\Charge::create(Array) #6 {main} throw in /customers/8/7/b/exammarked.com/httpd.www/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 110

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

var stripe = Stripe('*****');

function registerElements(elements, exampleName) {
  var formClass = '.' + exampleName;
  var example = document.querySelector(formClass);

  var form = example.querySelector('form');
  var resetButton = example.querySelector('a.reset');
  var error = form.querySelector('.error');
  var errorMessage = error.querySelector('.message');

  function enableInputs() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      form.querySelectorAll(
        "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='tel']"
      ),
      function(input) {
        input.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    );
  }

  function disableInputs() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      form.querySelectorAll(
        "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='tel']"
      ),
      function(input) {
        input.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      }
    );
  }

  function triggerBrowserValidation() {
    // The only way to trigger HTML5 form validation UI is to fake a user submit
    // event.
    var submit = document.createElement('input');
    submit.type = 'submit';
    submit.style.display = 'none';
    form.appendChild(submit);
    submit.click();
    submit.remove();
  }

  // Listen for errors from each Element, and show error messages in the UI.
  var savedErrors = {};
  elements.forEach(function(element, idx) {
    element.on('change', function(event) {
      if (event.error) {
        error.classList.add('visible');
        savedErrors[idx] = event.error.message;
        errorMessage.innerText = event.error.message;
      } else {
        savedErrors[idx] = null;

        // Loop over the saved errors and find the first one, if any.
        var nextError = Object.keys(savedErrors)
          .sort()
          .reduce(function(maybeFoundError, key) {
            return maybeFoundError || savedErrors[key];
          }, null);

        if (nextError) {
          // Now that they've fixed the current error, show another one.
          errorMessage.innerText = nextError;
        } else {
          // The user fixed the last error; no more errors.
          error.classList.remove('visible');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // Listen on the form's 'submit' handler...
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Trigger HTML5 validation UI on the form if any of the inputs fail
    // validation.
    var plainInputsValid = true;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.querySelectorAll('input'), function(
      input
    ) {
      if (input.checkValidity && !input.checkValidity()) {
        plainInputsValid = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (!plainInputsValid) {
      triggerBrowserValidation();
      return;
    }

    // Show a loading screen...
    example.classList.add('submitting');

    // Disable all inputs.
    disableInputs();

    // Gather additional customer data we may have collected in our form.
    var name = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-name');
    var address1 = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-address');
    var city = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-city');
    var state = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-state');
    var zip = form.querySelector('#' + exampleName + '-zip');
    var additionalData = {
      name: name ? name.value : undefined,
      address_line1: address1 ? address1.value : undefined,
      address_city: city ? city.value : undefined,
      address_state: state ? state.value : undefined,
      address_zip: zip ? zip.value : undefined,
    };

    // Use Stripe.js to create a token. We only need to pass in one Element
    // from the Element group in order to create a token. We can also pass
    // in the additional customer data we collected in our form.
    stripe.createToken(elements[0], additionalData).then(function(result) {
      // Stop loading!
      example.classList.remove('submitting');

      if (result.token) {
        // If we received a token, show the token ID.
        example.querySelector('.token').innerText = result.token.id;
        example.classList.add('submitted');
      } else {
        // Otherwise, un-disable inputs.
        enableInputs();
      }
    });
  });

  resetButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Resetting the form (instead of setting the value to `''` for each input)
    // helps us clear webkit autofill styles.
    form.reset();

    // Clear each Element.
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.clear();
    });

    // Reset error state as well.
    error.classList.remove('visible');

    // Resetting the form does not un-disable inputs, so we need to do it separately:
    enableInputs();
    example.classList.remove('submitted');
  });

}
```

**Other JS file:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var stripe = Stripe('*****');

  var elements = stripe.elements();

  var elementStyles = {
    base: {
      color: '#555',
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontSize: '15px',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',

      ':focus': {
        color: '#424770',
      },

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#555',
      },

      ':focus::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7DF',
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#555',
      ':focus': {
        color: '#FA755A',
      },
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#FFCCA5',
      },
    },
  };

  var elementClasses = {
    focus: 'focus',
    empty: 'empty',
    invalid: 'invalid',
  };

  var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: elementStyles,
    classes: elementClasses,
    placeholder: "Card Number",
  });
  cardNumber.mount('#example3-card-number');

  var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
    style: elementStyles,
    classes: elementClasses,
    placeholder: "Expiry (MM/YY)",
  });
  cardExpiry.mount('#example3-card-expiry');

  var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    style: elementStyles,
    classes: elementClasses,
    placeholder: "Security Code (CVC)",
  });
  cardCvc.mount('#example3-card-cvc');

  registerElements([cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc], 'example3');
})();
```

APIRESOURCE.PHP

```
<?php

namespace Stripe;

/**
 * Class ApiResource
 *
 * @package Stripe
 */
abstract class ApiResource extends StripeObject
{
    private static $HEADERS_TO_PERSIST = array('Stripe-Account' => true, 'Stripe-Version' => true);

    public static function baseUrl()
    {
        return Stripe::$apiBase;
    }

    /**
     * @return ApiResource The refreshed resource.
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        $requestor = new ApiRequestor($this->_opts->apiKey, static::baseUrl());
        $url = $this->instanceUrl();

        list($response, $this->_opts->apiKey) = $requestor->request(
            'get',
            $url,
            $this->_retrieveOptions,
            $this->_opts->headers
        );
        $this->setLastResponse($response);
        $this->refreshFrom($response->json, $this->_opts);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string The name of the class, with namespacing and underscores
     *    stripped.
     */
    public static function className()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        // Useful for namespaces: Foo\Charge
        if ($postfixNamespaces = strrchr($class, '\\')) {
            $class = substr($postfixNamespaces, 1);
        }
        // Useful for underscored 'namespaces': Foo_Charge
        if ($postfixFakeNamespaces = strrchr($class, '')) {
            $class = $postfixFakeNamespaces;
        }
        if (substr($class, 0, strlen('Stripe')) == 'Stripe') {
            $class = substr($class, strlen('Stripe'));
        }
        $class = str_replace('_', '', $class);
        $name = urlencode($class);
        $name = strtolower($name);
        return $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string The endpoint URL for the given class.
     */
    public static function classUrl()
    {
        $base = static::className();
        return "/v1/${base}s";
    }

    /**
     * @return string The instance endpoint URL for the given class.
     */
    public static function resourceUrl($id)
    {
        if ($id === null) {
            $class = get_called_class();
            $message = "Could not determine which URL to request: "
               . "$class instance has invalid ID: $id";
            throw new Error\InvalidRequest($message, null);
        }
        $id = Util\Util::utf8($id);
        $base = static::classUrl();
        $extn = urlencode($id);
        return "$base/$extn";
    }

    /**
     * @return string The full API URL for this API resource.
     */
    public function instanceUrl()
    {
        return static::resourceUrl($this['id']);
    }

    protected static function _validateParams($params = null)
    {
        if ($params && !is_array($params)) {
            $message = "You must pass an array as the first argument to Stripe API "
               . "method calls.  (HINT: an example call to create a charge "
               . "would be: \"Stripe\\Charge::create(array('amount' => 100, "
               . "'currency' => 'usd', 'card' => array('number' => "
               . "4242424242424242, 'exp_month' => 5, 'exp_year' => 2015)))\")";
            throw new Error\Api($message);
        }
    }

    protected function _request($method, $url, $params = array(), $options = null)
    {
        $opts = $this->_opts->merge($options);
        list($resp, $options) = static::_staticRequest($method, $url, $params, $opts);
        $this->setLastResponse($resp);
        return array($resp->json, $options);
    }

    protected static function _staticRequest($method, $url, $params, $options)
    {
        $opts = Util\RequestOptions::parse($options);
        $requestor = new ApiRequestor($opts->apiKey, static::baseUrl());
        list($response, $opts->apiKey) = $requestor->request($method, $url, $params, $opts->headers);
        foreach ($opts->headers as $k => $v) {
            if (!array_key_exists($k, self::$HEADERS_TO_PERSIST)) {
                unset($opts->headers[$k]);
            }
        }
        return array($response, $opts);
    }

    protected static function _retrieve($id, $options = null)
    {
        $opts = Util\RequestOptions::parse($options);
        $instance = new static($id, $opts);
        $instance->refresh();
        return $instance;
    }

    protected static function _all($params = null, $options = null)
    {
        self::_validateParams($params);
        $url = static::classUrl();

        list($response, $opts) = static::_staticRequest('get', $url, $params, $options);
        $obj = Util\Util::convertToStripeObject($response->json, $opts);
        if (!is_a($obj, 'Stripe\\Collection')) {
            $class = get_class($obj);
            $message = "Expected type \"Stripe\\Collection\", got \"$class\" instead";
            throw new Error\Api($message);
        }
        $obj->setLastResponse($response);
        $obj->setRequestParams($params);
        return $obj;
    }

    protected static function _create($params = null, $options = null)
    {
        self::_validateParams($params);
        $url = static::classUrl();

        list($response, $opts) = static::_staticRequest('post', $url, $params, $options);
        $obj = Util\Util::convertToStripeObject($response->json, $opts);
        $obj->setLastResponse($response);
        return $obj;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id The ID of the API resource to update.
     * @param array|null $params
     * @param array|string|null $opts
     *
     * @return ApiResource the updated API resource
     */
    protected static function _update($id, $params = null, $options = null)
    {
        self::_validateParams($params);
        $url = static::resourceUrl($id);

        list($response, $opts) = static::_staticRequest('post', $url, $params, $options);
        $obj = Util\Util::convertToStripeObject($response->json, $opts);
        $obj->setLastResponse($response);
        return $obj;
    }

    protected function _save($options = null)
    {
        $params = $this->serializeParameters();
        if (count($params) > 0) {
            $url = $this->instanceUrl();
            list($response, $opts) = $this->_request('post', $url, $params, $options);
            $this->refreshFrom($response, $opts);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _delete($params = null, $options = null)
    {
        self::_validateParams($params);

        $url = $this->instanceUrl();
        list($response, $opts) = $this->_request('delete', $url, $params, $options);
        $this->refreshFrom($response, $opts);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

APIREQUESTOR.PHP

```
<?php

namespace Stripe;

/**
 * Class ApiRequestor
 *
 * @package Stripe
 */
class ApiRequestor
{
    private $_apiKey;

    private $_apiBase;

    private static $_httpClient;

    public function __construct($apiKey = null, $apiBase = null)
    {
        $this->_apiKey = $apiKey;
        if (!$apiBase) {
            $apiBase = Stripe::$apiBase;
        }
        $this->_apiBase = $apiBase;
    }

    private static function _encodeObjects($d)
    {
        if ($d instanceof ApiResource) {
            return Util\Util::utf8($d->id);
        } elseif ($d === true) {
            return 'true';
        } elseif ($d === false) {
            return 'false';
        } elseif (is_array($d)) {
            $res = array();
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $res[$k] = self::_encodeObjects($v);
            }
            return $res;
        } else {
            return Util\Util::utf8($d);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|null $params
     * @param array|null $headers
     *
     * @return array An array whose first element is an API response and second
     *    element is the API key used to make the request.
     */
    public function request($method, $url, $params = null, $headers = null)
    {
        if (!$params) {
            $params = array();
        }
        if (!$headers) {
            $headers = array();
        }
        list($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $myApiKey) =
        $this->_requestRaw($method, $url, $params, $headers);
        $json = $this->_interpretResponse($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders);
        $resp = new ApiResponse($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $json);
        return array($resp, $myApiKey);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $rbody A JSON string.
     * @param int $rcode
     * @param array $rheaders
     * @param array $resp
     *
     * @throws Error\InvalidRequest if the error is caused by the user.
     * @throws Error\Authentication if the error is caused by a lack of
     *    permissions.
     * @throws Error\Permission if the error is caused by insufficient
     *    permissions.
     * @throws Error\Card if the error is the error code is 402 (payment
     *    required)
     * @throws Error\RateLimit if the error is caused by too many requests
     *    hitting the API.
     * @throws Error\Api otherwise.
     */
    public function handleApiError($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $resp)
    {
        if (!is_array($resp) || !isset($resp['error'])) {
            $msg = "Invalid response object from API: $rbody "
              . "(HTTP response code was $rcode)";
            throw new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        }

        $error = $resp['error'];
        $msg = isset($error['message']) ? $error['message'] : null;
        $param = isset($error['param']) ? $error['param'] : null;
        $code = isset($error['code']) ? $error['code'] : null;

        switch ($rcode) {
            case 400:
                // 'rate_limit' code is deprecated, but left here for backwards compatibility
                // for API versions earlier than 2015-09-08
                if ($code == 'rate_limit') {
                    throw new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
                }

                // intentional fall-through
            case 404:
                throw new Error\InvalidRequest($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            case 401:
                throw new Error\Authentication($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            case 402:
                throw new Error\Card($msg, $param, $code, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            case 403:
                throw new Error\Permission($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            case 429:
                throw new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            default:
                throw new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        }
    }

    private static function _formatAppInfo($appInfo)
    {
        if ($appInfo !== null) {
            $string = $appInfo['name'];
            if ($appInfo['version'] !== null) {
                $string .= '/' . $appInfo['version'];
            }
            if ($appInfo['url'] !== null) {
                $string .= ' (' . $appInfo['url'] . ')';
            }
            return $string;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static function _defaultHeaders($apiKey)
    {
        $appInfo = Stripe::getAppInfo();

        $uaString = 'Stripe/v1 PhpBindings/' . Stripe::VERSION;

        $langVersion = phpversion();
        $uname = php_uname();

        $httplib = 'unknown';
        $ssllib = 'unknown';

        if (function_exists('curl_version')) {
            $curlVersion = curl_version();
            $httplib = 'curl ' . $curlVersion['version'];
            $ssllib = $curlVersion['ssl_version'];
        }

        $appInfo = Stripe::getAppInfo();
        $ua = array(
            'bindings_version' => Stripe::VERSION,
            'lang' => 'php',
            'lang_version' => $langVersion,
            'publisher' => 'stripe',
            'uname' => $uname,
            'httplib' => $httplib,
            'ssllib' => $ssllib,
        );
        if ($appInfo !== null) {
            $uaString .= ' ' . self::_formatAppInfo($appInfo);
            $ua['application'] = $appInfo;
        }

        $defaultHeaders = array(
            'X-Stripe-Client-User-Agent' => json_encode($ua),
            'User-Agent' => $uaString,
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiKey,
        );
        return $defaultHeaders;
    }

    private function _requestRaw($method, $url, $params, $headers)
    {
        $myApiKey = $this->_apiKey;
        if (!$myApiKey) {
            $myApiKey = Stripe::$apiKey;
        }

        if (!$myApiKey) {
            $msg = 'No API key provided.  (HINT: set your API key using '
              . '"Stripe::setApiKey(<API-KEY>)".  You can generate API keys from '
              . 'the Stripe web interface.  See https://stripe.com/api for '
              . 'details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.';
            throw new Error\Authentication($msg);
        }

        $absUrl = $this->_apiBase.$url;
        $params = self::_encodeObjects($params);
        $defaultHeaders = $this->_defaultHeaders($myApiKey);
        if (Stripe::$apiVersion) {
            $defaultHeaders['Stripe-Version'] = Stripe::$apiVersion;
        }

        if (Stripe::$accountId) {
            $defaultHeaders['Stripe-Account'] = Stripe::$accountId;
        }

        $hasFile = false;
        $hasCurlFile = class_exists('\CURLFile', false);
        foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
            if (is_resource($v)) {
                $hasFile = true;
                $params[$k] = self::_processResourceParam($v, $hasCurlFile);
            } elseif ($hasCurlFile && $v instanceof \CURLFile) {
                $hasFile = true;
            }
        }

        if ($hasFile) {
            $defaultHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
        } else {
            $defaultHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        }

        $combinedHeaders = array_merge($defaultHeaders, $headers);
        $rawHeaders = array();

        foreach ($combinedHeaders as $header => $value) {
            $rawHeaders[] = $header . ': ' . $value;
        }

        list($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders) = $this->httpClient()->request(
            $method,
            $absUrl,
            $rawHeaders,
            $params,
            $hasFile
        );
        return array($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $myApiKey);
    }

    private function _processResourceParam($resource, $hasCurlFile)
    {
        if (get_resource_type($resource) !== 'stream') {
            throw new Error\Api(
                'Attempted to upload a resource that is not a stream'
            );
        }

        $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($resource);
        if ($metaData['wrapper_type'] !== 'plainfile') {
            throw new Error\Api(
                'Only plainfile resource streams are supported'
            );
        }

        if ($hasCurlFile) {
            // We don't have the filename or mimetype, but the API doesn't care
            return new \CURLFile($metaData['uri']);
        } else {
            return '@'.$metaData['uri'];
        }
    }

    private function _interpretResponse($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders)
    {
        $resp = json_decode($rbody, true);
        $jsonError = json_last_error();
        if ($resp === null && $jsonError !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            $msg = "Invalid response body from API: $rbody "
              . "(HTTP response code was $rcode, json_last_error() was $jsonError)";
            throw new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody);
        }

        if ($rcode < 200 || $rcode >= 300) {
            $this->handleApiError($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $resp);
        }
        return $resp;
    }

    public static function setHttpClient($client)
    {
        self::$_httpClient = $client;
    }

    private function httpClient()
    {
        if (!self::$_httpClient) {
            self::$_httpClient = HttpClient\CurlClient::instance();
        }
        return self::$_httpClient;
    }
}
```

CHARGE.PHP

```
<?php 

//include Stripe library
require_once ('./stripe/init.php');

// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_jfrwNbzP7kUm6kbXSHHDkqce");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
]);

?>
```

Comment: It appears you've just posted your API key, you'll want to revoke that immediately.

Comment: Can you include the PHP code that is relevant to the error?

Comment: Ok, will include those PHP files.. there's just a lot of them because they are all part of the stripe package.. no the API key is a test one so it's fine

Comment: @DarraghEnright ok both added now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, but what you should provide is the PHP code you wrote where you are using the Stripe library. This is the likely source of the error, not the JS or the Stripe library code.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I think it is likely to be the js code, as that tends to be the error in cases I've seen.. but of course you could be right! Will add my charge.php but that's the only php I've written & there's not much!

Comment: @DarraghEnright ok everything added now! :)

Comment: Okay, great—I assume the error is happening because `$token` is null. Have you tried validating that the token is being passed to the backend correctly? You are performing a regular form POST right?

Comment: Ok, sorry but could you quickly explain how I'd do that check or is it a lengthly process? I'm pretty new to javascript/php

Comment: To have `stripeToken` available in `$_POST` in your PHP code, you need to be sure that your JS code is adding the token value to a (hidden) form field with name `stripeToken`. There is code in `index.js` that handles the form submit event, and in that there is a `stripe`createToken` call. I don't really see that you are doing that, so I would check that